# How to simulating css zoom in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, zooming, scale

I use this code for a menu in my site but now testing it cross-browser I see there is not compatible with firefox.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none inside none;
    text-align: center;
}
li a:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #F00;
    margin: 0 auto 14px;
    transition: all .2s;
}
ul.small li a:before {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
   -o-transform: scale(0.7);
   background: blue;
}
ul.small-zoom li a:before {
    zoom: 0.7;
    background: green;
}
```

As you can see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shyghar/y2cy7xy5/7/) I tryed multiple solutions but I need the list item change width and heigth based on the a:before element and, with the scale() instruction the li dimention do not change.

[image]

There is a solution to have this in Firefow whitout fix the li dimentions?

Comment: I can't figure it out either.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom says that "unlike CSS Transforms, zoom affects the layout size of the element."  That's important because `transform: scale` does not change the layout size, but `zoom` does.  I can't figure out a workaround using standard CSS that will do exactly what zoom does with respect to layout size.

Comment: fireFox does not support zoom property using css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179710/css-zoom-property-in-the-firefox/55454507#55454507

Answer (score 2):

I mostly use JavaScript to emulate zoom. Since Firefox is the only modern browser not to support it, I occasionally use it in cases where its absence does not negatively impact usability.

Here is a quick and dirty version of a generic solution:

```html
<div data-zoom="0.5" style="zoom: 0.5">
  Scaled down element
</div>
```

```js
if (! ('zoom' in document.createElement('div').style)) {
  setInterval(() => {
    zoomed.forEach(e => {
      const scale = Number(e.getAttribute('data-zoom'))
      e.style.transform = 'none !important'
      e.style.marginRight = '0 !important'
      e.style.marginBottom = '0 !important'
      const width = e.clientWidth
      const height = e.clientHeight
      e.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`
      e.style.transformOrigin = '0 0'
      const pullUp = height - height * scale
      const pullLeft = width - width * scale
      e.style.marginBottom = `${-pullUp}px`
      e.style.marginRight = `${-pullLeft}px`
    })
  }, 100)
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a quick and dirty solution, but it works for my use-case, so it could help someone else too.

```
.zoomed {
  zoom: 0.5;
}
```

becomes

```
.zoomed {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  margin: -50px;
}
```

where 50px is 1/4 of the `.zoomed` width.

Of course, there are many limitations of this approach - it overwrites any previous `transform` and `margin`, you have to manually insert the negative margin for each element (or calculate it with JS), and probably more.

But like I said, it worked for my specific use-case.

Answer (score -3):

There is no such CSS standard property like `zoom`.

The reason why you code does not work in modern browsers, is that you are missing the unprefixed (standard) variant of several properties. For example when using `transform`:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
-moz-transform: scale(0.7);
-ms-transform: scale(0.7);
-o-transform: scale(0.7);
transform: scale(0.7);
```

Comment: zoom is a non-standard http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/ and isnt supported in FF

Comment: @Shyghar I saw your fiddle and even played around with before posting this answer. What did you mean?

Comment: @feeela In my fiddle there is a rule ( ul.small li a:before ) with the exact code you post. I ask in my question if there is a way to change li dimentions according the a:before dimetions. The scale transformation does not do that. So your answer was in my question..

Comment: @Shyghar …but as of the version history of your question, this answer was only added to the question, after I posted it. So I answered that question, you copy&pasted the answer to the question and then tell me, it was already there. Yeah, sure.