# CSS Zoom property in the Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, zooming

I set almost all sizes in pixels and based resolution depending scaling based on `zoom` property on `body`. And after that I got to know that Firefox doesn't support it at all.

I found solution to use transform scale and origin, but it change width and height of entire page and it's not that I expect.

I don't want to rewrite sizes of all elements for each resolution just because Firefox, I can do it with only one string with `zoom` property.

Is there any solutions for my situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I zoom an HTML element in Firefox and Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049342/how-can-i-zoom-an-html-element-in-firefox-and-opera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't zoom your page or anything using css in firefox, because fire not support zoom property... readmore>> [How can I zoom an HTML element in Firefox and Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049342/how-can-i-zoom-an-html-element-in-firefox-and-opera/55454473#55454473)